# Proper way to have a resource available by both association and by itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, I apologize for the poor title - I'm trying to think of a better way to explain it in a few words for that, but can't think of one.

Basically, as an example (note the model names are just examples; I know the actual concept of tasks being associated to many projects doesn't make too much sense):

- Project model
- Task model
- Each task can be assigned to many projects

I want to be able to view a project's tasks at:
/projects/1/tasks

OR view all tasks in all projects at: /tasks

But having two controllers for this doesn't seem very DRY and doesn't seem like the Rails way. Is there a better way?

Comment: why would that need two controllers?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is essentially two routes to the same resources.

```
resources :tasks
resources :projects
match projects/:id/tasks => 'tasks#index'
```

In your TasksController#index, check for params[:id]

```
def index
  if params[:id]
      @tasks = Project.find(params[:id]).tasks
  else
      @tasks = Tasks.all
  end
  respond_with(@tasks)
end
```